# How to query for formula fields in test classes

Tags: apex, soql, formula-field, unit-test

From what I understand, formula fields are calculated when a record is opened/read.

If a record is created by a controller extension and then queried then it's never really opened or read, so consequently the formula fields are returned as null when I try to query for them.

Does anyone know how to workaround this? I have tried to update writable fields on the required records (like below) but this does not work either.

Any help appreciated.

```
List <custom_object__c> Record = [SELECT formula_field__C , writable_field__c FROM custom_object__c];

    record[0].writable_field__c = 'updated value';
    update record;
    system.debug(Record.formula_field__C);
    -----
    RESULT: DEBUG - Null
```

Answer (score 5):

They are calculated on query (read). In your code, for example, you'd have to do this:

```
List <custom_object__c> Record = [SELECT formula_field__C , writable_field__c FROM custom_object__c];

record[0].writable_field__c = 'updated value';
update record;
Record = [SELECT formula_field__C , writable_field__c FROM custom_object__c];
system.debug(Record[0].formula_field__C);
```

When you change a record via a DML statement, the in-memory version isn't changed (except for the ID field, if it was an insert). You need to query the record again to get the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response sfdcfox. I actually tried this before posting, it doesn't work either. At least not for me anyway. 
I have double checked with my code and I'm still getting null. 

Also, is it normal for null values to be excluded when I query for all fields in an object? I have to query for the specific field individually to find out that it's null.

Comment: You might be missing something else elsewhere. I know there was a bug with formulas in the earlier API versions, but that has since been fixed. And querying all fields is the same as just querying specific fields, so I don't see why this should cause a problem.